# How can I filter a vector based on regex list in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a character string vector that I would like to filter based on keywords from a second vector.

Below is a small reprex:

```
list1 <- c("I like apples", "I eat bread", "Bananas are my favorite")
fruit <- c("apple","banana")
```

I am presuming I will be needing to use `stringr`/`stringi`, but I would, in essence, like to do something alongs the lines of `list1 %in% fruit` and it return `T,F,T`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `str_dectect`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(list1) %>%
  mutate(Flag = str_detect(list1, paste0("(?i)", paste0(fruit, collapse = "|"))))
                    list1  Flag
1           I like apples  TRUE
2             I eat bread FALSE
3 Bananas are my favorite  TRUE
```

If you want to `filter`(i.e. subset) your data:

```
data.frame(list1) %>%
  filter(str_detect(list1, paste0("(?i)", paste0(fruit, collapse = "|"))))
                    list1
1           I like apples
2 Bananas are my favorite
```

Note that `(?i)` is used to make the match case-insensitive.

**EDIT**:

To record the matches in a separate column you can use `str_extract`(if you expect to have just one match per string) or `str_extract_all`(for more than one matches):

```
data.frame(list1) %>%
  mutate(Flag = str_detect(list1, paste0("(?i)", paste0(fruit, collapse = "|"))),
         Match = str_extract_all(list1, paste0("(?i)", paste0(fruit, collapse = "|"))))
                    list1  Flag  Match
1           I like apples  TRUE  apple
2             I eat bread FALSE       
3 Bananas are my favorite  TRUE Banana
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great and works perfectly. To build on this, is it possible for the Flag column to display which word it has picked up in the list?

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `grepl` without using external packages.

`grepl` can handle multiple patterns separated by `|`, therefore we can first concatenate the strings in `fruit` together with `|` as the separator.

Remember to set `ignore.case = TRUE` if you don't care about case (note the "banana" in your example has different case).

```
grepl(paste(fruit, collapse = "|"), list1, ignore.case = T)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or use `grep` to directly output the string that match:

```
# same as list1[grepl(paste(fruit, collapse = "|"), list1, ignore.case = T)]
grep(paste(fruit, collapse = "|"), list1, ignore.case = T, value = T)
[1] "I like apples"           "Bananas are my favorite"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful and well explained!